# move vertex on plane / face

Tags: vertices, transforms, faces

I'm being frustrated by this simple task: I want to move the marked vertex, but it's supposed to only move on its surface. Reason being, I want to subdivide the surface into a specific shape. ...Tried for hours, searched online for hours, just couldn't find it out. I assume its more simple than I think it is, but I just can't get it to work. Can you help me?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your transform orientation from *Global* to *Normal* then grab the vertex with <kbd>G</kbd> and restrict it from the local normal Z-axis by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Z</kbd>

[image: Norm]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to switch your transform orientation back to global afterwards or at some point, you'll wonder what the heck is happening later on.

Answer (score 0):

The vertex is part of the overall plane?  Select both faces.  "Create orientation" operation (ctrl alt space for me.)  Select the vertex and translate it constrained to XY (g shift-z move mouse confirm for me.)